# Date validation in form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to validate my form. I have a date input where I am checking to make sure the day is between 1 and 31, the month is between 0 and 12 and the year is between 1910 and 2019.

This is my code so far:

```js
var date = document.getElementById('dob');
var day = date.substring(0, 2);
var month = date.substring(3, 5);
var year = date.substring(6, 10);

if (year > 2019 || year < 1910) 
{
  valid = false;
  document.getElementById('dateValid').style.display = "inline-block";
} 
else 
{
  document.getElementById('dateValid').style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

this is my html code for the date field:

```
<div>
   <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob">
    <span class="error" id="dateValid">valid date required</span>

    </div>
```

I have repeated the above for the day and month. I am unsure why this wouldn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We need your full source code to analyze your problem :>

Comment: @DavidJapan the other javascript code is to validate my other inputs which are 'first name', 'last name' etc, all these work

Comment: Did you check the data type of date? if it's string you are comparing string against integer.

Answer (score 0):

Full source code would definitely help to answer the question. But from the limited information i sew here.
getElementById will give you the element.
You still need the value. Check what value are you getting in the date variable by console.log
Since I am not sure about the element 'dob', I can't comment on that. 
date.value should give you the value of the field.
The below should work:

```
var date = document.getElementById('dob').value;
var day = date.substring(0, 2);
var month = date.substring(3, 5);
```

Comment: as in my html for the date field as well?

Comment: var date = document.getElementById('dob');
This line would give you the input tag
<input type="date" name="dob" id="dob">

For fetching its value which is there in the field you need to get date.value which will give you the value of the input field

Comment: Replace this line 
var date = document.getElementById('dob');
by 
var date = document.getElementById('dob').value;

It will work

Have edited the answer for reference

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('dob')` will return html element so you can't use substring first. You need to get element value by `.value` . I provided illustration with input date ...

```js
function check() {
var date = document.getElementById('dob').value;
var day = date.substring(9, 2);
var month = date.substring(5, 2);
var year = date.substring(0, 4);
console.log(year)
var valid;

if (year > 2019 || year < 1910) 
{
  valid = false;
  //document.getElementById('dateValid').style.display = "inline-block";
} 
else 
{
  valid = true;
}

console.log(valid)
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="dob" onchange="check()">
```

Answer (score 0):

> Built-in form validation uses HTML5 form validation features. This validation generally doesn't require JavaScript. Built-in form validation has better performance than JavaScript. But, while highly customizable, native validation is not as customizable as JavaScript.[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation)

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

input:valid {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
     <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
     <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" min="1910-01-01" max="2019-12-31">
     <span class="error" id="dateValid">valid date required</span>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Please note that the max and min attributes of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.